# expectation on the inverse of norm-2 of complex Gaussian vector

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, inverse

I am working on deriving the normalization issue and face some challenges in finding the closed-form expression. Assume there is a complex vector $\mathbf{h}\in\mathcal{CN}^{P\times 1}$, where each entry independently follows the same complex Gaussian distribution with zero mean and variance $\gamma$. Is it possible to compute a closed-form solution for
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{\lVert \mathbf{h} \rVert^2} \right],
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes expectation operation and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ denotes the norm-2 operation, i.e., $\lVert \mathbf{h} \rVert^2 = \lvert h_1\rvert^2+\cdots+\lvert h_P\rvert^2$.

Truly appreciate any comments and suggestions!